# One Application to run on TV and Tablet (with gps)

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-tv

I have a Honeycomb application that my desire was it would run on both tablet and GoogleTV.  I have code in my application to handle situations differently dependent upon if the application is on a tv or tablet.

My application is not showing up on the GoogleTV market.  I have included in my manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/> 

and 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

Does anyone know that if by declaring permission of ...LOCATION would cause it not to be seen in the market?  If so, is there a way to include this code side if NOT tv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission implicitly requires the android.hardware.location.gps feature, which is not supported on Google TV.  Add

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false"/>
```

to your app's manifest to ensure that the feature is not required.

Answer (score 0):

There is no GPS support, instead, you should use

```
android.hardware.location
or
android.hardware.location.network
```

Comment: I understand that there is no GPS support on the TV.  I have conditional statements in my code dependent upon whether the device is a tv or a tablet (with gps).  I need the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION for my application to run on a tablet...can I use the same apk for both?  Is there a way to add the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION code side at runtime dependent upon if it is a tv or tablet?